# How to change UIImageView's image in another view controller?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimageview

I have a very simple, yet frustrating problem. In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, I am trying to change an `UIImageView` on another view, but unfortunately, it is not working, and the `UIImageView` stays the same.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MainViewController *demoController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    demoController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Demo Controller #%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
    self.sideMenu.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [self.sideMenu setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"server"] isEqualToString:@"imap.mail.me.com"]){
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"INBOX";
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"];
            demoController.imageBG.image = image;

        if (indexPath.row == 1)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Sent Messages";
        UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sentmail.png"];
        demoController.imageBG.image = image2;

        if (indexPath.row == 2)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Drafts";
        UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"drafts.png"];
        demoController.imageBG.image = image3;

        if (indexPath.row == 3)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Deleted Messages";
        UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trash.png"];
        demoController.imageBG.image = image4;

        if (indexPath.row == 4)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Archive";
        UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"archive.png"];
        demoController.imageBG.image = image5;

        if (indexPath.row == 5)
            theAppDelegate.folder = @"Junk";
        UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"junk.png"];
        demoController.imageBG.image = image6;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this line `if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"server"] isEqualToString:@"imap.mail.me.com"])` will get true means, your `demoController.imageBG.image` always have `junk.png`.

I think you missing `{}` between `if` body.

It have to be like this

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    theAppDelegate.folder = @"INBOX";
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inbox.png"];
    demoController.imageBG.image = image;    
}
 if (indexPath.row == 1)
     .........
```

**Note:** While you writting this type of coding better use `else-if` OR `switch-case`.

Comment: I have added the {} and it still does not change. Even before, I didn't even get the "junk.png".

Comment: Put break point to this line `if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"server"] isEqualToString:@"imap.mail.me.com"])` , Check whether this line gets true or false..

Comment: I know it is true, otherwise the folders wouldn't change, and they do.

Answer (score 0):

Fist you miss `{}` for `if` condition so here you get `junk.png` Image on your `UIImageView` every time...

Also here instead of your this logic you can simply pass the name of image in `NSString`...

just property-synthesize the string and pass in your `MainViewController` class like bellow...

=>`MainViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *strImageName;
```

=>`MainViewController.m`

```
@synthesize strImageName;
```

and just pass that name in this variable like you above code...

```
   if (indexPath.row == 0){
    theAppDelegate.folder = @"INBOX";
    demoController.strImageName = @"inbox.png";
    [demoController.strImageName retain];
   }
   else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        theAppDelegate.folder = @"Sent Messages";
    demoController.strImageName = @"sentmail.png";
    [demoController.strImageName retain];
   }
```

and in your `MainViewController`'s viewDidLoad method just assign this image like bellow..

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageName];
        imageBG.image = image;
}
```